# Creating classes from Postgres database for Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019, npgsql

Looking for a method to automatically create entity classes from existing Postgres 13 database.
in

According to

http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html

In Visual Studio 2019 command prompt

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Host=my_host;Database=my_db;Username=my_user;Password=my_pw" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
```

Command should do this but it throws error

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

NpgSql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL v5.0.1 package is installed from Nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install Dotnet EF tool.

try this in your package manager console

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

After that it is recommended to install design tool aswell so you can use tools on specific project

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```